# How to scroll programmatically to a position in a page to display desired content (as opposed to display the top of the page)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I see on some website (**like StackOverflow, yahoo, the US Homeland Security department, ...**) a word associated to a link that, when clicked, not only loads a page, but also, displays that page at the exact location where the contain related to the word starts.

How can I obtain that with ASP.NET MVC? (by the way, do I need javascript for that?)

Thanks for helping

Comment: [Why not check the answers of the exact same question you asked 3 minutes before this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087838/how-to-scroll-programmatically-to-a-position-in-a-page-to-display-desired-content)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href="#jumpHere">Go to the other content</a>
<a name="jumpHere">Some content</a>
```

Also the URL can have `/yourpage.html#jumpHere` or with variables, `/yourpage.html?var1=foo&var2=bar#jumpHere`.

Since we're talking about the hash (#), it's usually used for jumping to a specific part of the page. Because of that, it won't reload the whole page.  This is useful for web applications that move from one view to another using only AJAX.  To make each view bookmarkable, JavaScript "saves" the state (what view you are on) using `location.hash` to the URL.  The next time you open the URL, JavaScript reads it and loads the correct view.  In HTML5 this is superseded by `pushState`.

Answer (score 4):

1) Find the coordinates of the element on the page

2) `window.scrollTo(x,y)`

Comment: Since the OP asked for a "programmatical" way to do it that's what I posted. Yes, a simple hash is often the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a named anchor within the page. This will have the result you're talking about, almost like creating a "bookmark" within a page. No javascript required.

First, create the anchor using the `<a>` tag with the `name` attribute specified (in this case, `section1`):

```
<a name="section1"></a>
```

Then, to link to that anchor from the same page, just use something like this:

```
<a href="#section1">Go to Section 1</a>
```

If you're linking to that anchor from another page (in this case, `mypage.html`), append `#section1` at the end of the url:

```
<a href="mypage.html#section1">Go to Section 1 in MyPage.html</a>
```

For more information, see [here](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Its called an anchor tag.

Place this in your HTML.

```
<a name="name"></a>
```

If you call this URL, it will jump to that place.

```
html-file.html#name
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named anchor to do this with HTML, without javascript. [here is a link explaining this](http://www.weethet.nl/english/html_anchors.php).

Answer (score 1):

It is very simply done with id tag of differnt html elements
for eg :- an div element if it is having "footer" as its id and is placed at the bottom of the page then, http://url-address-to-thatpage.html*#footer* will load the page and scroll it too the footer. (adding the "#idoftheelement" after the page url)
It is also possible to load and scroll the page with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is with the "id" attribute if it's not an anchor tag you'd like to bookmark. For example:

```
<div id="bookmark1">Content...</div>
```

Then, you can link to it with an anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="#bookmark1">Go to content</a>
```

Or link to that spot on the page by appending a #bookmark1 to

```
http://yourwebsite.com/page#bookmark1
```